# Cookies staying until internet explorer is restarted

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I'm having this weird problem with internet explorer 8. Any cookies that I delete are still recognized until I restart the browser. The cookies get deleted fine in chrome and firefox, even without restarting those browsers. I tried searching for this but couldn't find anything, does anyone know any bugs related to this? I've tried using the following methods to delete the cookie:

```
PHP: setcookie("reservation", "", time() - 3600);   
jQuery cookie plugin: $.cookie('reservation', null);
```

I've tried this with and without specifying the domain, but this doesn't change anything.

So, to reiterate, any cookies I delete are still being recognized by internet explorer after I delete them, but once I close internet explorer and re-open it, the cookie is gone. It seems like it's tied to the session in some way.

Comment: Modify your tags - you have one for internet, one for explorer; it should be just one for "internet explorer." Anyway, I saw this in the PHP section, but it's not an issue with PHP.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but noticed a similar question on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/182311/cookies-are-retained-even-after-explicit-delete-in-ie8